# How to get particular columns from database

Tags: php

I want only 4 columns from database in below
I have to get only 4 column from database for displaying in textfield please give suggestion for that. The table is shown below thank you

[image]

```
    $sql_getnm = "SELECT * FROM util WHERE util_head IN ('wc_email', 'wc_contact_us', 'wc_mobile', 'wc_google_map');";
                $result_getnm = $connect->query($sql_getnm); 
                while($row_getnm = $result_getnm->fetch_array()) 

          $util_value_email_data=?
          $util_value_mobile_data=?;
          $util_value_map_data=?;
          $util_value_data=?;
```

html form

```
 <form  id="submitForm" method="post"  role="form" name="hl_form" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="box-body">
                   <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="mobile_number">Email*</label>
                      <input class="form-control" id="util_value_email" name="util_value_email" value="<?Php echo $util_value_email_data;  ?>" maxlength="250"  placeholder="Enter Email Address" type="text">
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="mobile_number">Mobile*</label>
                      <input class="form-control" id="util_value_mobile" name="util_value_mobile" value="<?Php echo $util_value_mobile_data; ?>" maxlength="250"  placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" type="text">
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="mobile_number">Map*</label>
                      <input class="form-control" id="util_value_map" name="util_value_map" value="<?Php echo $util_value_map_data;  ?>" maxlength="250"  placeholder="Enter Map Address" type="text">
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="description" class="required">Description*</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" style="resize: none;" id="util_value"  name="util_value" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Description"><?Php  echo $util_value_data; ?></textarea>
                   </div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: i want that 4 column data to textfield

Comment: You can use loop for each `key` and get the data in some `array` variable.

Comment: @yogendra yes i want only 4 value from database to display in textfield

Comment: By your query what are you getting? You can get all the key values by your query in a single query. What are you getting?

Comment: i am getting 4 values in my query

Comment: are you using wordpress? yes, then please tag wordpress in your question.

Comment: no i am working in core php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code from which you can get all the four data that you want.

```
$sql_getnm = "SELECT * FROM util WHERE util_head IN ('wc_email', 'wc_contact_us', 'wc_mobile', 'wc_google_map');";
$result_getnm = $connect->query($sql_getnm);

while($row_getnm = $result_getnm->fetch_array()) {
    if($row_getnm['util_head'] == 'wc_email'){
        $util_value_email_data = $row_getnm['util_value'];
    }
    if($row_getnm['util_head'] == 'wc_contact_us'){
        $util_value_contact_data = $row_getnm['util_value'];
    }
    if($row_getnm['util_head'] == 'wc_mobile'){
        $util_value_mobile_data = $row_getnm['util_value'];
    }
    if($row_getnm['util_head'] == 'wc_google_map'){
        $util_value_map_data = $row_getnm['util_value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because you are having key as values in your column. If that changed then you have to change in this function. I would suggest you to make one common function and get data from there by passing key in it. So in future if your key is change then it will not affect to your code. Use `Constant`  for your key.

Comment: If needed help in your dynamic code. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace * with columns name with comma separation.

```
$sql_getnm = "SELECT Columname1,Columname2,Columname3,Columname4 FROM util WHERE util_head IN ('wc_email', 'wc_contact_us', 'wc_mobile', 'wc_google_map');";
$result_getnm = $connect->query($sql_getnm); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_getnm, MYSQL_ASSOC) 

          $util_value_email_data= $row['Columname1'];
          $util_value_mobile_data= $row['Columname2'];
          $util_value_map_data= $row['Columname3'];
          $util_value_data= $row['Columname4'];
```

Comment: $util_value_email_data="info@example.com"
          $util_value_mobile_data="9999999991";
          $util_value_map_data="<iframe>";
          $util_value_data="<p>contact us details</p>";

Comment: i want this check with table

Comment: answer updated just replace Columname with actual Column name and you all set

Comment: which column name can you please tel me